# Phpmyadmin - Stored procedure with transaction isn't working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

So, I've been using XAMPP v3.2.2 with PHPmyadmin. I've tried to create a stored procedure using transactions with this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nuevoRegistro (IN fecha DATE, IN hora TIME, IN preciofecha DECIMAL(18,2), IN preciototal DECIMAL(18,2), IN notas TEXT, IN usuario_idusuario BIGINT(20), IN cliente_idcliente BIGINT(20), IN tarea_idtarea BIGINT(20))
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO registro VALUES('',fecha,hora,preciofecha,preciototal,notas,usuario_idusuario,cliente_idcliente,tarea_idtarea);

COMMIT;

END
```

My delimiter is //.
Phpmyadmin allows me to create the procedure with this, but when i call it my table registro isn't affected. What i'm doing wrong?.

Comment: My first guess is that you're getting a sqlwarning or sqlexception, and it's rolling back the transaction. For example, this would happen if you insert a bigint value into an int column, or something like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The table Registro has this form:
-----
idregistro - bigint(20),
fecha - date, 
hora - time, 
preciofecha - decimal(18,2),
preciototal - decimal(18,2),
notas - text,
usuario_idusuario - bigint(20),
cliente_idcliente - bigint(20),
tarea_idtarea - bigint(20)
-----
All in that order.
I've tried a stored procedure without the transaction and it works perfectly, but i really need the commit control in this query.